# While running the botium cli with luis connector the getting an assertion error even when the question and answers are right

Tags: botium-box

I had downloaded the botium luis connector sample code from github and trying out in botium cli with one of my bot . see the folder to see the files that  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjegK.jpg).and in package.json i have given a name from the brand Luis entity and in my convo file i have a question and answer from the entity products.
i tried to run the npm install and npm test from the folder  spec in cmd ,

I am getting an error says assertion failed ,but in actual scenario those question and answer are working good in bot.
Please see the error `E:\Botium_workspace\botium-connector-luis-master\botium-connector-luis-master\samples\Connector Test\spec>npm test`

E:\Botium_workspace\botium-connector-luis-master\botium-connector-luis-master\samples\Connector Test\spec>npm test

products@1.0.0 test E:\Botium_workspace\botium-connector-luis-master\botium-connector-luis-master\samples\Connector Test
mocha spec

EdgewellBrandLuis-Dev
    1) composite entities

0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

1) EdgewellBrandLuis-Dev
       composite entities:
     Error: composite entities/Line 6: Expected bot response (on Line 3: #me - What are the materials of the handle?) "undefined" to match one of "The handle is made up of Synthetic Rubber and aluminum plating. The Travel Case is made up of polypropylene. It does not contain other commonly questioned products such as latex, fragrances, whey, gluten, or animal products."

ASSERTION FAILED in TextMatchAsserter - Expected: ["The handle is made up of Synthetic Rubber and aluminum plating. The Travel Case is made up of polypropylene. It does not contain other commonly questioned products such as latex, fragrances, whey, gluten, or animal products."]  - Actual: empty
INPUT: What are the materials of the handle?

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

please see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9z6I.jpg).

Is there anything that I had to do other than doing the below steps
1)wrote a botium.json file with all the Capabilities and (the name of the project should be the name of the Luis App right ?)
2)write the test cases
3)set the package .json [as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz2BI.jpg)

4)npm install

5)npm test

6)also tried running botium cli run from the spec folder path

Comment: I have tried to run botium bindings for Luis connector 
I had used the scripting memory file and 
Convo yaml file with utterances
I was able to run it successfully
But when I used to run 
npm run mocha ,my test cases and the utterances are running
we should just run the Testcases right ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Botium LUIS Connector](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-luis) does not work with plain text - LUIS is only for intent and entity resolution. There won't be any plain text answers to assert in your test cases, but you have to use the INTENT and ENTITY asserters instead:

```
composite entities

#me
want to buy 2 business ticket

#bot
INTENT buy_ticket
ENTITIES TestCompositeEntity.builtin.number|TestCompositeEntity.TravelClass
ENTITY_VALUES 2|Business
```

**2020-04-08: Updated for more details**

So you have a LUIS workspace with intents, entities and entity synonyms. My suggestions are:

1. Use [Botium Scripting Memory](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/26411023/Botium+Scripting+Memory) to list all synonyms for a product you want to test:

```
     |$product          
Utt1 |Sense Shave cream
Utt2 |Sense cream
Utt3 |Hydro shave cream
```

*Scripting Memory has to be enabled separately, see Botium Wiki link above*

2. For all user examples for an intent you want to test, use utterances lists - you can use the synonym list here:

```
UTT_ABOUT_PRODUCT
tell me about $product
about the $product
i am interested in $product
can you tell me something about $product
```

3. A convo file (the test case) uses the utterances and the [Botium NLP Asserters](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/17334319/NLP+Asserter+Intents+Entities+Confidence) for NLP verification:

```
TC01_ABOUT_PRODUCT

#me
UTT_ABOUT_PRODUCT

#bot
INTENT AboutProduct
INTENT_CONFIDENCE 70
ENTITIES Products
```

It checks for
* the correct intent
* a baseline intent confidence
* an entity has been recognized

**You can also use YAML instead of plain text:**

```
convos:
  - name: TC01_ABOUT_PRODUCT
    steps:
      - me:
          - UTT_ABOUT_PRODUCT
      - bot:
          - INTENT AboutProduct
          - INTENT_CONFIDENCE 70
          - ENTITIES Products
utterances:
  UTT_ABOUT_PRODUCT:
    - tell me about $product
    - about the $product
    - i am interested in $product
    - can you tell me something about $product
```

Comment: Thanks @florian ,So I am able to do it
,so how can i test Json with n number of intents and entities,should i write n number of text convo file or is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: please give an example what you mean with "json with n number of intents and entities" (update the original question)

Comment: ,please find the below to see the structure of my Luis apps Json file ,with intense and utterance .My doubt is how I can write test cases for those intents and utterances?